# Serialise a list of objects to file with Protobuf-net, then read back one at a time

Tags: protobuf-net

I need to serialise a number of objects to file, so was looking to give ProtoBuf-Net a try. One requirement is that I need to be able to deserialise the objects one at a time at a later date, so my first thought was to use `Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix` & `Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`.

I then saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272947/981831) which seemed to suggest that it may be possible to add the objects to a list then serialise this with a single call, but still be able to deserialise the individual objects one at a time afterwards. However I can't see the methods mentioned (`SerializeItems` && `DeserializeItems`), although it was an old article so I'm guessing these have been deprecated?

Am I best sticking with De/SerializeWithLengthPrefix, or is there a more efficient way to serialise a few thousand objects in one go, yet still be able to deserialise them one by one afterwards?

Comment: Those methods still exist... https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/d12763cd24820c4861bf723efd3d2d26aa7fcb13/src/protobuf-net/Serializer.cs#L278

Comment: `DeserializeItems` exists, but there is no SerializeItems.  For serialization of a list/collection, I think you are meant to use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` , which still requires iteration through the items.